# Lync Online API

Tags: lync-2010, lync

I'm not familiar with Lync at all.

Is there a way to communicate with Lync Online without having to install the client in the server.
We aer in the need of creating a Windows service that will be in charge of scheduling meetings based on some data in our system.

Everything that I have read points to having the client installed in the computer, but this seems kind of odd. I thought Microsoft would have a Web Service accepting messages to manipulate and pull information from Lync Server.

Please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out a similar thread on MSDN:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/communicatorsdk/thread/a736afdd-eba6-4d26-8668-84c40cb19494

It says you can run Lync in "suppression mode"... probably not what you were looking for, but one step up from a visible client.

Comment: I guess there's no other way of doing it. Thanks for your help.